# Useful properties of Hilbert-Schmidt operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, integral-equations

I understand a Hilbert-Schmidt operator is a compact operator so due to that fact alone it has some nice properties.

But as being Hilbert-Schmidt is a stronger property than just being compact, what do we gain by knowing an operator is Hilbert-Schmidt? How does it help us in applications?

Comment: The fact we can use the Hilbert-Schmidt inner-product $\langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{trace}(A^*B)$ is probably the most useful property to keep in mind.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How is that useful applications? Is it more efficient to compute? Has it any relation to the usual $L^2$ inner product?

Comment: what do you mean "more efficient to compute"? It's the *only* sensible inner product on operators. It's like the $L^2$ inner product in that it is also an inner product. The Hilbert Schmidt operators are nicer than the bounded operators in precisely the same way that $L^2$ is nicer than $L^\infty$.